# Borrar registro ignorando id IDENTITY EF C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es que quiero borrar una fila con solo el `numParte` (que es el identificador normal que uso), pero tengo un problema:

**CÓDIGO DE BORRADO**

```
//BORRAR PARTES REVERSE
        public void BorrarPartesReverse(string parte)
        {
            try
            {
                var datosRemover = new Reverse
                {
                    numParte=parte
                };

                using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
                {
                    ctx.Entry(datosRemover).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Cuando paso por esta sección:

```
var datosRemover = new Reverse
{
    numParte=parte
};
```

El rellena todo los datos de la tabla como `null`, excepto `numParte` que la pone como `parte`, pero me he fijado que `id` lo rellena como 0, puesto que según, este no puede quedar nulo, a la hora de entrar al using el no puede hacer el borrado por que no hay `id=0` que tenga la parte que le envie a `numParte`, lo que genera un error.

Puedo recuperar el id usando la siguiente linea:

```
var entidad=ctx.Reverse.where(x=x.numParte==parte).select(m=>m.id).FirstOfDefault();
```

para ya despues quede asi:

```
var datosRemover = new Reverse
    {
        id=entidad.id,
        numParte=parte
    };
```

Hay alguna forma de poder evitar la linea anterior, como decir, asigneme este numero de `parte` pero omita el `id`?

PD: No puedo usar el `id` para borrar, por que tengo 2 tablas que guarda datos con el numero de `numParte`, por eso ocupo que borre solo con `numParte`, si lo borrara por `id`, en la primera tabla serviria, pero en la segunda o me borraria un registro que no corresponda a la tabla o un `id` que no exista.

Comment: Baker. La tabla que muestras tiene llave principal? Es decir, tienes "id" como llave primaria de la tabla? Si es así, la otra tabla de la que hablas (y sería genial que la describieras), tiene id como llave foránea?

Comment: @Arriel, No ninguna de las tablas tienes PK

Comment: Puede que tu error esté ahí. El change tracker de entity framework no te permitirá trabajar con entidades sin llaves primarias. Eso únicamente funciona si los datos son de sólo lectura. Si quieres borrar esa entrada será con un query al contexto, o tendrás que añadir una llave primaria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te da error por que el borrado en EF debe hacer referencia al dato de la base de datos y no a un objeto nuevo, debes escribir lo siguiente.

```
var entidad=ctx.Reverse.Where(x=> x.parte==parte).FirstOrDefault();
```

Con esa línea seleccionas el elemento a borrar y luego para borrarlo ejecutas lo siguiente.

```
ctx.Reverse.Remove(entidad);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Funciono bien, gracias!!